# Python XML parser not functioning as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml

So I was making a XML parser and it doesn't work. It only returns "name" when I try to get the `name` attribute and not the value. Here is the Python code:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class get:
    @staticmethod
    def xml(id: str, element_name: str, xml_file: str):
        try:
            tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
            root = tree.getroot()
            
            for user in root.findall('user'):
                found_id = user.get("id")
                
                if found_id == id:
                    element = user.find(element_name)
                    if element is not None:
                        return element.text
                    else:
                        return None
            return None
        except ET.ParseError as e:
            print(f"Error parsing XML: {e}")
            return None
```

And Here is the XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<user id="1">
    <name>USER_NAME</name>
    <age>USER_AGE</age>
    <gender>USER_GENDER</gender>
    <sexuality>USER_SEXUALITY</sexuality>
    <dating_status>USER_DATING_STATUS</dating_status>
    <profession>USER_PROFESSION</profession>
</user>
```

Can Someone help me fix this?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, your code looks for `user` children of the root element, but in the XML file you show, the `user` element *is* the root element. What’s up with that?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Do you mean: if user.get(‘id’) == 1.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using xmltodict

```
    $ pip install xmltodict
    $ python
    Python 3.11.5 (main, Aug 24 2023, 15:18:16) [Clang 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import xmltodict
    >>> x = """\
    ... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    ... <user id="1">
    ...     <name>USER_NAME</name>
    ...     <age>USER_AGE</age>
    ...     <gender>USER_GENDER</gender>
    ...     <sexuality>USER_SEXUALITY</sexuality>
    ...     <dating_status>USER_DATING_STATUS</dating_status>
    ...     <profession>USER_PROFESSION</profession>
    ... </user>\
    ... """
    >>> d = xmltodict.parse(x)
    >>> print(d)
    {'user': {'@id': '1', 'name': 'USER_NAME', 'age': 'USER_AGE', 'gender': 'USER_GENDER', 'sexuality': 'USER_SEXUALITY', 'dating_status': 'USER_DATING_STATUS', 'profession': 'USER_PROFESSION'}}
    >>> print(d['user']['name'])
    USER_NAME
    >>>
    >>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Class names should be named with capital letters.
(But I recommend for such easy xml structure, use `pandas.read_xml()`).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from io import StringIO

xml = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<users>
<user id="1">
    <name>Adam</name>
    <age>15000</age>
    <gender>Male</gender>
    <sexuality>USER_SEXUALITY</sexuality>
    <dating_status>USER_DATING_STATUS</dating_status>
    <profession>USER_PROFESSION</profession>
</user>
<user id="2">
    <name>Eva</name>
    <age>10000</age>
    <gender>Female</gender>
    <sexuality>USER_SEXUALITY</sexuality>
    <dating_status>USER_DATING_STATUS</dating_status>
    <profession>USER_PROFESSION</profession>
</user>
</users>"""

xml_file = StringIO(xml)

class GET:

    @classmethod
    def parse_xml(cls, xml_file):
        tree = ET.parse(xml_file)
        root = tree.getroot()
        return root

    @staticmethod
    def amount_user(root):
        # get the amount of users
        x_user = len(root.findall('.//user'))
        return x_user

    @staticmethod
    def xml_el(id, tag_name):
        # parse the given element name
        id = str(id)
        tag_name = tag_name
        user = root.find(f'.//user[@id="{id}"]')

        for elem in user.iter(tag_name):
            return (user.tag, user.get('id'), elem.tag, elem.text)

# -------       

root = GET.parse_xml(xml_file)
x_user = GET.amount_user(root)
print("Amount of user", x_user)

tag_names = ['name', 'age', 'gender'] # extend the list with your tag
for i in range(x_user):
    user_id = str(i+1)
    for tag in tag_names:
        tag, id, tag_name, tex = GET.xml_el(user_id, tag)
        print(f"{tag} {id} # {tag_name}: {tex}")
```

Output:

```
Amount of user 2
user 1 # name: Adam
user 1 # age: 15000
user 1 # gender: Male
user 2 # name: Eva
user 2 # age: 10000
user 2 # gender: Female
```